# Justificar QRDDRichText

Tags: delphi

Estou Criando um relatório em Delphi usando o `QuickReport`.

No Banco de dados eu gravo um texto formatado (isto eh, com partes justificadas, outras alinhada a esquerda outras centralizada).

Para justificar o texto no `TDBrichedt` eu usei o seguinte código:

```
procedure TfrmAnotacoes.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  SendMessage(edtAnot.handle,
              EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS,
              TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY,
              TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY)
end;



    procedure TfrmAnotacoes.JustifyRichEdit(RichEdit :TCustomRichEdit; AllText :Boolean);
    var
      ParaFormat :TParaFormat;
      SelStart,
      SelLength :Integer;
    begin
      ParaFormat.cbSize := SizeOf(ParaFormat);
        SelStart := RichEdit.SelStart;
        SelLength := RichEdit.SelLength;
        if AllText then
          RichEdit.SelectAll;
        ParaFormat.dwMask := PFM_ALIGNMENT;
        ParaFormat.wAlignment := PFA_JUSTIFY;
        SendMessage(RichEdit.handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, LongInt(@ParaFormat));
    // Restaura seleção caso tenhamos mudado para All
        RichEdit.SelStart := SelStart;
        RichEdit.SelLength := SelLength;
    end;
```

Gostaria de justificar o texto no `QRDBRichText` como ele vem do banco, mas não estou conseguindo!

Answer (score 2):

Ate onde conheço, real problema é que o componente Não suporta alinhamento justificado, o que você pode fazer e se tiver conhecimento para tanto, é, alterar a classe do componente e adicionar esta propriedade, isto é de nível Alto.

**Como contornar a situação?**

Formate o texto em um `Rich` comum no formulário, quando chamar o `DBRich` você passa o texto para ele, na leitura dos dados do Banco para o `DBRich` ele realmente perde a formatação!

Aqui uma `Procedure` que poderá te ajudar:

```
{uses RichEdit;}
procedure JustifyText;
  var Format: TParaFormat2; // declarada na RichEdit.pas
begin
  FillChar(Format, SizeOf(TParaFormat2), 0);
  Format.cbSize := SizeOf(TParaFormat2);
  Format.dwMask := PFM_ALIGNMENT; 
  Format.wAlignment := PFA_JUSTIFY;
{Dependendo da implementação do componente, o paragrafo sairá alinhado a esquerda ao invés de justificado. Neste caso será necessário atualizar para um compativel com o formato RTF 3.0}
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, LPARAM(@Format));
end;
```

PS: Abandonei o QReport a séculos devido essas bobagens por falta de implementação, Relatórios toscos e difíceis de formatar! Existe boas ferramentas hoje em dia de facil utilização como `FastReport` ou `RaveReport`. Dentre outras...

Comment: o rich e o dbrich estão ok, o ruim eh que o quickreport eh usado em um gerador de relatório aqui da empresa, então não eh tão facil abandonar ele

Comment: não entendi. vc quiz dizer "Existe boas ferramentas hoje em dia de facil utilização como "nada""? é isso? =P

Comment: O amigo desculpe-me, é que cortou quando enviei a resposta do editor de textos!, Vou editar e adicionar!